# Call to jquery function from external file

Tags: file, function, drop-down-menu, external, aquery

I Have a Jquery file ("Maestro.js") and a function:

```
    function SetDDLNumbers () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_ShuttersCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_CollectedCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_ValimCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_UCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_ShoeingCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_EnginCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_ProtectedSpaceCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_GlassCount').append(new Option(i, i));
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder3_BoxesCount').append(new Option(i, i));
        }
    });

My asp file and the PageLoad function is : 

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)Session["selectedrow"];
        int ProjectID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);

        DBservices db = new DBservices();
        DataTable dt = db.GetCustomerInformation(ProjectID);

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetPageDetails(dt);
            SetProjCurrentStatus();
            LoadSuppliers();
        }

        GetOrderStatus();
    }
```

The aspx file is a content page of master page tha contain this line :

```
<script src="javascript/maestro.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want to call the SetDDLNumbers function within the "!Page.IsPostBack" section.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                SetPageDetails(dt);
                SetProjCurrentStatus();
                LoadSuppliers();
            }
```

When I'm try to wrote :  SetDDLNumbers() it show me that that function is not recognized.
how can i call this function?